# How to load dynamically generated iframe in Highslide

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, highslide

How can I load a dynamically generated iframe in Highslide? The html part:

```
<div id="fr">Get iframe</div>
<div id="test999">This is a test</div>
<p><iframe id="ifr"></iframe></p>
```

The jQuery part:

```
$(function () {
    $("#fr").click(function() {
    $('iframe').contents().find('body').html($('#test999').html());
    return hs.htmlExpand(this,{ contentId: 'ifr',objectType: 'iframe' } );
});
```

When clicking "Get iframe", Highslide keeps spinning the loader, but does't open the window?

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: any error on web console? and what is `hs` in return statement

Comment: No errors. hs is a common syntax for Highslide (http://highslide.com/ref/hs.objectType). It works fine if I open a div as html, but I need to open it in modal iframe window.

Answer (score 0):

See this example: http://www.roadrash.no/hs-support/example-iframe-with-controlbar.html

So proper structure:

```
<a href="include-short.htm" onclick="return hs.htmlExpand(this, { objectType: 'iframe', contentId: 'controlbar5' } )">
    Content in iframe
</a>

<div class="highslide-html-content" id="controlbar5"> </div>
```